# Why aren't all elements of the $45_a$ representation of $SO(10)$ zero?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

We can write elements of the $45_a$, where $a$ denotes antisymmetric, as $10 \times 10 $ matrices, because

$$ 10 \otimes 10 = 1_s \oplus 54_s \oplus 45_a$$

Here $10$ denotes the fundamental $10$-dimensional representation of $SO(10)$.

Thus we have for the matrix elements

$$ (45_a)_{ij}=10_i 10_j - 10_j 10_i $$

Why isn't this zero for all $i,j$?

Comment: I can't make any sense of this notation. What does $10_i 10_j$ mean? Is this a tensor product or what?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh sorry! $10_i$ denotes the $i$-th element of the fundamental $10$ representation that we can write, for example, using weights: $$ 10= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{1,0,0,0,0\} \\
 \{0,1,0,0,0\} \\
 \{0,0,1,0,0\} \\
 \{0,0,0,1,0\} \\
 \{0,0,0,0,1\} \\
 \{0,0,0,0,-1\} \\
 \{0,0,0,-1,0\} \\
 \{0,0,-1,0,0\} \\
 \{0,-1,0,0,0\} \\
 \{-1,0,0,0,0\} \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ Then the product $10_i 10_j$ yields the $ij$ element of the tensor product representation $10 \otimes 10$, which means in terms of weights, that we add the $10_i$ weight to the $10_j$ weight.

Comment: Okay, so it's a tensor product. Then the answer is that the tensor product of vectors isn't commutative: that is, if $v, w \in V$ are vectors in the same vector space, then $v \otimes w \neq w \otimes v \in V \otimes V$. (It is true that if $v$ and $w$ are weight vectors then $v \otimes w$ and $w \otimes v$ have the same weight. But they aren't the same vector.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay thanks. But if the resulting weight vector is the same, what is or where are they different? If we have for $10_1= \{1,0,0,0,0\} $ and  $10_2= \{0,1,0,0,0\} $  that $10_1 10_2 =  \{1,1,0,0,0\} $ and $10_2 10_1=  \{1,1,0,0,0\} $, too. Why isn't $10_1 10_2 - 10_2 10_1 =  \{1,1,0,0,0\} - \{1,1,0,0,0\} =0$?

Comment: Like I said: two vectors in a representation can have the same weight without being the same vector. (As a silly example, one vector could be twice the other. But in general weight spaces can be larger than $1$-dimensional.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks again. Is there any way to compute how the two vectors corresponding to the same weight differ? The thing I can think of is when I compute the $10 \times 10$ matrix as explained above, the matrix has symmetric weight vector entries. This means that we have one element in the tensor product rep corresponding to some weight given by   $$\left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) $$ and another one corresponding to the same weight by  $$\left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) $$.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the right picture.